# Windows Service process gets killed instead of stopped

Tags: java, c, windows, multithreading, service

I wrote a program in C which launches a `JavaVM` in a thread and checks for new versions of another service in the main loop. This program runs as a service on Windows. That means the required service methods are implemented:

```
 void ControlHandler(DWORD request) {
        switch (request) {
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
            SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
            break;
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
            SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
            break;
        }
        return;
    }
```

The shutdown process writes a file named "`terminate`" on the harddisk and opens a socket-connection to the JavaVM (which is waiting for this connection of course). This is just a trigger which tells the JavaVM to check for the "terminate" file, delete this file and shut down correctly. When this is done, the service also terminates correctly.
When I shut down the service via `sc stop MyServiceName`, everything works fine: File gets created, JavaVM terminates, Service stops within approximately one second.
But when I shut down or restart the computer the process just gets killed. The terminate-file gets created, but there is no log entry in the JavaVM log or the service log that the service got shut down correctly.
Can I somehow programmatically tell the service control manager to wait for this service?

Comment: Did you set the `SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN` flag in the `SERVICE_STATUS` structure passed to the last `SetServiceStatus` call?

Comment: Hi, yeah the SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN is set. Funny thing is, it just doesn't work at shutdown. If I control the service using services.msc it writes the logs and everything.

Comment: Actually if I've understood the process correctly, the fact that the file `terminate` is being created indicates that the service successfully received the stop request?  My second guess is that JavaVM is noticing that the system is shutting down and exiting before your code can respond.  I don't know enough about JavaVM to say whether that is a sensible guess or not or how you would fix it if so, but it might be worth your checking out.  (It might look to JavaVM as though control-C had been pressed, if that makes any sense in this context.)

Comment: ... but do make sure that you've set a suitable wait hint in `ServiceStatus`.